Fluid not showing
I have a basic setup of a teapot, a UV Sphere inside the pot and the cube around the scene.
The teapot should be the effector, the UV sphere the flow source and the cube the domain. When i set all the fluid settings and bake it, it's not showing any fluid. However it is working without the teapot so i assume it has something to do with the interaction of pot and domain.







hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Stupid question: why is the teapot effector set to Is Planar? It does not look very planar to me. But the first thing I can see, the Resolution Divisions of the domain are much too low. You see the small cube in the bottom left corner of the domain? That's the voxel size with a resolution of 64, now compare that to the teapot and guess how often it would fit inside the nozzle...

Thanks @GordonBrinkmann
The Resolution Devisions were the point. I upscaled it and now it is working. ‍♂️
